Как правильней организовать структуру обработчиков в Laravel?
Всем привет. Подскажите, кто уже работает в конторах на Laravel, как вы организовываете структуру обработчиков в продакшн проектах?
Объясняю. Изучаю программирование на Laravel, хочу сделать приложение с большой формой, с каждым полем из формы нужно поработать, в частности загружаются 4 файла, которые нужно распихать по нужным директориям и добавить их название в БД, также текстовые данные нужно обработать и распихать по таблицам в БД... В общем, я начал писать обработку в Контроллере, там всё получаю, обрабатываю, всё ок, но задумался... Правильно ли это, что такой большой обработчик на несколько десяток строк в одной функции контроллера? И вспомнил, что уже не помню кто, говорил мне, что много кода в контроллер функции - есть плохо, нужно как то делить код, толи запихивать в отдельные классы и потом просто вызывать эти методы в контроллере или как то так.. Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильней всё-таки делать, если можно на примитивном примере...

А разве в документации в Laravel ничего не написано про это? Мне казалось там всё есть и даже рекомендуемая структура папок

"если можно на примитивном примере..." ---- это текст для статьи, а не для ответа.... так что как минимум вам надо в поисковике искать что-то типа такого https://habr.com/ru/articles/760022/
